# Design of Table when it comes to multiple dates for selection

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I have a table `Hall` which has structure like

```
CREATE TABLE Hall_tbl (
    hall_id INTeger PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    price INTEGER,
    capacity INTEGER,
    availibility INTEGER
);
```

Now, intention of the application is to make it work in a way that User looks at the calendar -> Selects a date -> If Hall is available on that particular day then User can interact with it else not.

So, it boils down to the point that `Availibility` is important and it should be reference to bunch of `Dates`. Once user  open a particular date, he is presented with `Time Slots`. Depending on the `Available Time Slots` user can select the Hall. I am having hard time in getting idea how would it be possible to implement that.

First I thought to create a table called `dates` with columns date starting from 1-1-2018 to 1-1-2020 and create multiple time slot like `0-1` `1-2` .. `2-24` and putting `0` to indicate they are not sold and I will change to `1` when User select an open `Hall`. But this will take me to create 365*4 rows and 25 columns which is not at all efficient. So how can I do this ?

Many application related to Ticket Booking, Flight booking have already implemented such stuff. So, How do they do it efficiently ??

Technology I am using is `SQLITE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a table for the opening dates and add just the opening dates and then check if there is a row for the date if so then the hall is open otherwise it is not.

So based upon your Hall_tbl your could have :-

#### Your Hall_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hall_tbl (
    hall_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    price INTEGER,
    capacity INTEGER,
    availibility INTEGER
);
```

- `AUTOINCREMENT` isn't required and it is recommended to not use it unless necessary [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- availability column isn't required but has been left

#### Add some halls (4 id's 1-4)

```
INSERT INTO  Hall_tbl (name, price, capacity, availibility)
    VALUES('Grand Hall',200,50,0), 
        ('Large Hall',100,25,0), 
        ('Normal Hall',75,20,0),
        ('Small Hall',50,15,0);
```

#### The Hall opening times table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hall_opening_times (hall_reference, open_date);
```

#### Add some opening times (5)

```
INSERT INTO hall_opening_times 
    VALUES (1,'2018-04-23'), -- Grand hall open on 2018-04-23 
           (2,'2018-04-23'), -- Large Hall open on 2018-04-23
           (2,'2018-04-25'), -- Large Hall open on 2018-04-25
           (3,'2018-04-24'), -- Normal Hall open on 2018-04-24
           (4,'2018-04-23'); -- Small Hall open on 2018-04-23
```

#### Checking if a hall is open

The following would return a single row with a single column where the value would be 0 (not open) or 1 (open) :-

This checks the Grand Hall for today (it's 2018-04-23 here)

```
SELECT count() > 0 AS hall_open  FROM hall_opening_times WHERE hall_reference = 1 AND date(open_date) = date('now');
```

- it returns 1 (in column **`hall_open`**) as the Grand Hall (ID = 1) is open on 2018-04-03 today (`date('now')`)

This one checks the Normal Hall for today

```
SELECT count() > 0 AS hall_open  FROM hall_opening_times WHERE hall_reference = 3 AND date(open_date) = date('now');
```

- it returns 0 (in column hall_open) as there are no entries for ID 3 on 2018-04-03

---

#### A little more

You could get a list of Open Halls using the following :-

```
SELECT group_concat(name,' - ') AS open_halls 
FROM hall_opening_times JOIN Hall_tbl ON hall_reference = Hall_tbl.hall_id
WHERE open_date = date('now')
```

Which on 2018-04-23 would return (in column open_halls):-

**Grand Hall - Large Hall - Small Hall**

If the previous SQL were change to (to check tomorrow 2018-04-24) :-

```
SELECT group_concat(name,' - ') AS open_halls 
FROM hall_opening_times JOIN Hall_tbl ON hall_reference = Hall_tbl.hall_id
WHERE open_date = date('now','+1 DAY')
```

Then it would return :-

**Normal Hall**

You could prune past open_times (if wanted) using something like :-

```
DELETE FROM hall_opening_times WHERE open_date < date('now','-1 WEEK');
```

- will delete rows older than 1 week from the current date.

### Note regarding date formats

The date format yyyy-MM-dd is one recognised/supported by SQLite date functions using that rather than d-M-yyyy can make things significantly simpler.

- See - [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Is `hall_reference` a Foreign Key to the `Hall_tbl` ? because let's say we want to fetch related information like `capacity` , `price` from `Hall_tbl` .

Comment: Yes, although there is no need to define it as `FOREIGN KEY` as this simply adds a constraint (**hall_reference** must match a **Hall.tbl.hall_id**). Yes you can get the capacity and price e.g. the examples in "A Little More" use the **name** column for example.